# Will Comodo SSL work on a subdomain which points to external server using DNS zone editor?

Tags: ssl, dns, cpanel

I have a domain called qlink.co.in and I have a cpanel for this domain.

In cpanel I created a sub domain - server1.quicklink.co.in

In this cpanel in DNS zone editor I pointed this sub domain to my server1 like shown in image below -

[image]

Now I can access my http://server1 IP address. My link as http://server1.qlink.co.in/.

If I install `ssl` on my `qlink.co.in` domain which comes with unlimited sub domain option, then do I need to do anything on my server1 server or not? Will my subdomain link work with `https`?

Answer (score 0):

SSL should be installed on domain from the server where your domain is pointing. As your sub-domain is pointing to other provider's server, you should install the SSL from that server.

It will not work, if you will install it from the server where your main domain is pointing.

Comment: my other server which is point to a sub domain is ip based, ssl is installed on a domain and not ip, right ????  and according to you the way i am trying to do, it will not work..did i understood right, i need to install ssl on the server which is joining to sub domain ?

Comment: That's correct! You will need to install the SSL on sub-domain from the server where it is pointing to. (that is where it is joining)